# Handling multiple connections to the host simultaneously

Tags: hadoop, nutch

How can I handle a number of connections to the host at the same time?

Comment: that depends very much on what 'this => the problem you are having' is! Please expand!

Comment: I build search engine using nutch over hadoop. I generated segment to fetch (~ 1 000 000 pages). When I run fetcher number of connection to the host at the same was about 300. How can I limit it?

P.S. sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From nutch-default.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>fetcher.threads.fetch</name>
  <value>10</value>
  <description>The number of FetcherThreads the fetcher should use.
    This is also determines the maximum number of requests that are 
    made at once (each FetcherThread handles one connection).</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fetcher.threads.per.host</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>This number is the maximum number of threads that
    should be allowed to access a host at one time.</description>
</property>
```

As noted above, the number of connections is at most equal to the number of threads. The first property controls the overall number of connections and the second the number of connections per host - this is the one you need to set.